# getting argument from excel to R

Tags: r, excel

I am caling R Script from excel through Macro.

In excel i have three cells as Area

```
           Area 
DEHRADUN    Delhi   MUMBAI
```

these areas is args[1],args[2],args[3] respectively. Now , i am using the below code

```
AreaIn<-NULL
AreaIn<-c(1:3)
for(k in 1:3){
      AreaIn[k]<-as.character(args[AreaIn[k]])
    }
```

to get AreaIn as **c('DEHRADUN','Delhi','MUMBAI')** .

but i am getting AreaIn as "DEHRADUN" only. Can somebody please tell me how to do it.

NOTE: I have just taken part of code needed for this question from a larger code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `AreaIn` as numeric or integer using `AreaIn<-c(1:3)` at first.

But then change the type to `character` in the loop using:

`AreaIn[k]<-as.character(args[AreaIn[k]])`

If you run the following diagnosis, you will find what's going on:

```
 args <- c("A","B","C")
  AreaIn<-NULL
  AreaIn<-c(1:3)
  for(k in 1:3){
    cat(class(AreaIn),AreaIn,"\n")
    AreaIn[k]<-as.character(args[AreaIn[k]])
    cat(class(AreaIn),AreaIn,"\n")

  }
```

output:

```
integer 1 2 3 
character A 2 3 
character A 2 3 
character A NA 3 
character A NA 3 
character A NA NA
```

If you just need a copy of `args`, why not `AreaIn <- args`?

Comment: thanks... didnt realise it was such a rookie mistake. Thanks a ton.